# How to auto-complete commands by typing first letter?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, auto-completion

In the terminal, how can I show history while typing? 
Is this possible? what is the library that I have to install?
I think this will boost my productivity while using the terminal, 
currently I search commands by pressing up-down arrows, but sometimes it take time to reach the command I want..

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: you do know that you can press Tab for autocomplete right ? you'd have to add the parameters though

Comment: please see the gif above, once he type a letter, a suggestion is printed in the terminal in gray color without any tab..

Comment: The gif looks like fish shell (https://fishshell.com/)

Comment: Check this, this will show you autosuggestion with auto-completion. https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [fishshell](https://fishshell.com/) to me. To install and configure follow the link and instructions

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand the question but you could put an alias for various commands in .bashrc which is located in your home directory.

as an example to be more specific

choose your editor

sudo gedit `/.bashrc

add the following line (preferably near the bottom and don't forget to use # to describe your alias for future reference)

alias z='df -h'

you may need to reload .bashrc

if you have multiple entries you wish to add it is suggested in the original .bashrc file to create a seperate .bashrc_aliases file.

Comment: please see the gif above, once he type a letter, a suggestion matches the typed character is printed in the terminal in gray color

Comment: This is not the solution. The gif was not animated when I looked at it.

Comment: I wish I know the way to do it, it will save lots of time while typing..

Comment: There must be some short script to tell bash to read previous entries and insert them into the shell upon recognition of the letters.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the termianl you can press Ctrl+R and then either type in the beginning of the word, or search for a keyword and it'll prompt a suggestion. The Ctrl-R is a reverse serach in the bash_history.

Another way is to use the history command like this: "history 20" and you'll get the twenty latest commands you have used.